Copy-and-paste answers/comments from wiki page or the likes
I have been seeing comments or answers which attempt to answer or help addressing the OP's question by copy-and-pasting from a wiki page or the likes. IMHO, there are several issues with doing so:

Some of those pages are horribly formatted, making it barely readable.
Sometimes, only some part of the pasted section is helpful. Pasting all can potentially lead to further confusion.
If the OP complies with the general guidelines to asking a constructive question, one could safely assume that he/she has done some research and apparently has not found the answer with a few minutes of google search.

While copy-and-pasting might not itself be bad, doing so without careful consideration can lead to low-quality posts. 
Should there be a flag to discourage such behavior? What do you guys think?
